# Can we place two textviews in footer xml file in android?

Tags: android

I am displaying a **header and footer for a listview**. Here I am displaying all the data dynamically. Now I want to keep a **title** to my footer...So I tried to keep another **textview in my footer.xml file**. But it is not accepting. How can I place a title for my footer data?

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exptext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Help me regarding this...Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
using two layout one is using the textview and other is using the listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="welcome" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="welcome" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Another XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hi I have changed only the type of layout i.e from linear to relative as you said and I am now able to add another textview to the footer.xml file...thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Do I get you right? You want to place a TextView above and one below a ListView?
Than you have to do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

The Important part ist the layout_weight attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
you can us two xml one is set the two textview and other xml used the listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="welcome" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="welcome" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Another XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```